# Neo4j: subtract from epoc millisec and return result in hours or days in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j 3.3 which doesnt support `Datetime`. Is there a way I can subtract a date which is a string from a time (in epoc millisec) and return result in either hours or days? Is there a better way than this:

```
return apoc.date.convert(
 apoc.date.currentTimestamp() - 
 apoc.date.parse("2019-12-04 12:31:00", 'ms',"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), 
'ms', 'h')
>> 26
```

How can I return the result in hours or days instead of epocmillis?

Answer (score 0):

As you've identified, for versions of Neo4j before 3.4, you will need to use APOC to assist you in converting epoch into hours/days.

If you're working with very small time intervals (e.g. between days/hours and not months), you can always manually calculate those values as you won't need to allow for leap years/etc.